# What is the "M" next to functions in iOS/Swift signify?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

What does the label M mean next to the 4 functions that have popped up in the autocomplete when I started to type 'login...'.

Noob here, so learning a few basics.
[image: Screenshot image showing the label M]

Comment: Blue symbols are methods. 'A' is IBAction, 'M' is Method, and 'P' is a Property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**M** stands for ***method***, which is notation convention of Apple. Here You are trying to use the method of delegate.
You will find **C** for ***Class*** and **P** for ***Variables and Constants***
[image]

Comment: thanks for the complete listing. I will ask yours as answer as soon as SO lets me, in like 8 mins :)

Comment: "P" stands for "Property".

Comment: indeed p for property ultimately they are either variable or constants !